# Content assist in Eclipse does not work for EL in JSP files

Tags: eclipse, jsp, el

I'm developing a Spring MVC web app in Eclipse Kepler (JEE edition). I'm using plain JSP as view technology.

I put a model on the request as an attribute and read it from the request in the JSP using 'useBean'.

When I do this, content assist fails for this object inside EL (expression language). It works however for:

- my bean object within scriptlet code
- standard objects that are always available in JSP (even inside EL!)

In other words: content assist works fine, except when I try it on a bean from inside an EL construct.

Summarizing the problem in code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" type="org.myorg.PageModel" scope="request" />
THIS WORKS - a property of a prefined object: ${pageContext.request.... }
THIS WORKS - write out property from 'pageModel' in scriptlet code: <%= pageModel.... %>
THIS DOES NOT - write out property from 'pageModel' in EL: ${pageModel....}
```

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set up all the files you need for content assist? Here's a link that might help: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftsrcedt023.html

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307240 ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast: that's not it. `${pageContext.xxx}` wouldn't have worked either then.

Comment: Have you tried with Eclipse Juno or SpringToolSuite?

Comment: I ended up moving to IntelliJ. Nothing seemed to work..

Answer (score 1):

JSP page by default ignores EL, so try

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Funny thing: after almost 2 years I thought I'd give it a try with a brand new Eclipse install (Mars), but the problem is still there!